# Conditional Maximum Likelihood - How is marginal probability of inputs are independent of the parameter we are estimating?

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

I am reading "A Primer in Econometric Theory" by John Stachurski and reading the part on Conditional Maximum Likelihood. There I have seen the same kind of maximization I have seen before in other sources too: In order to estimate the parameter of a distribution, author uses conditional maximum likelihood  and he does not take into account the marginal density of inputs when maximizing the objective function. I have seen it being done before, but he openly says marginal density is independent of the parameter we are estimating. Let me explain what I am asking:

Suppose we have inputs and outputs in our model, $x$ being the input and $y$ being the output: $x_1, x_2$...$x_N$ and $y_1, y_2$...$y_N$. They come in pairs. Each observation $x_i$ is probably a vector but $y_i$ is just a scalar. Our pair is $(x_i, y_i)$. Our aim is to estimate $\theta$ in $p(y|x;\theta)$ in order to pin down the conditional density of $y$ given $x$.

So we maximize the following condition:

$l(\theta) = \sum_{n=1}^{N}\text{ln}\,p(x_n,y_n;\theta)$ where $p$ is the joint density of $(x_n,y_n)$.

Letting $\pi$ be the marginal density of $x$, we can decompose the joint density as:

$p(x,y;\theta) = p(y|x;\theta)\pi(x)$.

Here author says the following:

"The density $\pi(x)$ is unknown but we have not parameterized it because we aren't trying to estimate it. We can now rewrite the log likelihood as

$l(\theta) = \sum_{n=1}^{N}\text{ln}\,p(y_n|x_n;\theta) + \sum_{n=1}^{N}\text{ln}\,\pi(x_n)$

The second term on the right-hand side is independent of $\theta$ and as such it does not affect the maximizer"

And he goes on just maximizing the first part, the conditional probability.

Here is my question: Is not $\pi(x)$ dependent on $\theta$ somehow? My thinking is convoluted but both $p(y|x;\theta)$ and $\pi(x)$ are derived from the same underlying joint density: $p(x, y;\theta)$. $\pi(x)$ is just a short hand for

$\pi(x) = \int p(x,y;\theta)dy$ which is clearly dependent on $\theta$. Once you plug this into your maximization problem, it becomes:

$l(\theta) = \sum_{n=1}^{N}\text{ln}\,p(y_n|x_n;\theta) + \sum_{n=1}^{N}\text{ln}\,\int p(x,y;\theta)dy$

Now the second item is also dependent on $\theta$ and need to be taken into account when maximizing wrt $\theta$. Am I missing something here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the way you set up your model. For example, this is a perfectly valid model:

$$
X \sim N(0, \sigma^2) \\
Y|X \sim N( \mu, \gamma^2)
$$

Then, we may write $\theta = (\sigma^2, \mu, \gamma^2)$ and so:

$$
p(X,Y;\theta) = p(Y|X;\theta)p(X;\theta) = p(Y|X; \mu, \gamma^2) p(X|\sigma^2)
$$